# How to send an Image name from a collection view to another View Controller in Swift?

Tags: ios, segue, collectionview

This might end up being a really simple thing but I've been pondering over it for half and hour.

I have an Image View on a View Controller. From there I Modal to a Collection View with Images. I want to select an image from the Collection View and have it show up on the Image View on the first View Controller.

I can get to Collection View and get the indexPath but can't figure out what to do next.

```
class ImageCollectionViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource {

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
        self.dismissModalViewControllerAnimated(true)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may create a delegate for your modal controller and implement it in the parent view controller. Just remind to assign modal controller delegate in the `prepareForSegue` implementation. I wrote an article on protocol and delegation in Swift, you can read it [here](http://nscurious.com/?p=55) to get any help.

Comment: I can handle all that. What I can't understand is that I have the indexPath of the image which is an integer. How do I get the actual Image to show from the indexPath inside didSelectItemAtIndexPath?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for. It worked for me:

```
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {

    var yourIndexPath = indexPath
    var selectedCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(yourIndexPath) as ArchiveCells
    var imageInCell = selectedCell.yourCellImageName.image

    //whatever else you need to do
    self.dismissModalViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```